# 01422. 00000 - "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DECLARE 
    EMPLEADO EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
    SALARIO EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
    select employee_id , salary INTO EMPLEADO , SALARIO
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID > = '100' AND EMPLOYEE_ID < = '120';
    IF SALARIO > 100000 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El salario actual del empleado '||empleado||' es de '||salario||'.'|| 'Es un excelente salario');
    elsif SALARIO > 9000 AND SALARIO < 100000 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El salario actual del empleado '||empleado||' es de '||salario||'.'|| 'Es un salario normal');
    ELSIF SALARIO < 9000 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El salario actual del empleado '||empleado||' es de '||salario||'.'|| 'Es un salario normal');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PL/SQL ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779483/pl-sql-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-rows)

Comment: What is confusing?  Your query returns multiple rows and by putting the values in variables, you are assuming only one row.

Comment: How would it be the right way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get a list of all employees? You don't need the variables or INTO, just the result of the SELECT.

Comment: Divide according to your salary if the employee's salary is excellent, normal or needs an increase

Comment: By the way, you're saying <9000 is normal, copy paste error.

Comment: I have already corrected it, this is the error
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 5
01422. 00000 - "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
* Cause: The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
* Action: Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with a cursor:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  CURSOR CURSOR1 IS
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY
      FROM EMPLOYEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID >= '100' AND EMPLOYEE_ID <= '120';          
EMPLEADO EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
SALARIO EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN CURSOR1 LOOP
    EMPLEADO := REC.EMPLOYEE_ID;
    SALARIO := REC.SALARY;
    IF SALARIO > 100000 THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El salario actual del empleado '||empleado||' es de '||salario||'.'|| 'Es un excelente salario');
    ELSIF SALARIO > 9000 AND SALARIO < 100000 THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El salario actual del empleado '||empleado||' es de '||salario||'.'|| 'Es un salario normal');
    ELSIF SALARIO < 9000 THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El salario actual del empleado '||empleado||' es de '||salario||'.'|| 'Es un salario normal');
    END IF;
    EMPLEADO := NULL;
    SALARIO := NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

As Nicholas V. pointed out, you are indicating that a salary < 9000 is also normal - this is likely a typo.