# PLS-00201: identifier 'SALARY' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is my procedure:

```
create or replace procedure emp_lookup
 (empno   IN  emp55.empno%TYPE,
  salary  OUT emp55.sal%TYPE,
  empname OUT emp55.ename%TYPE)
is
begin 
  select sal , ename INTO salary, empname
  from   emp55 
  where  empno=empno;

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN empname:='null';
  salary:=-1;
END;
```

This is the calling code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE 
  employee_name emp55.ename%TYPE;
  employee_salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
  emp_lookup (3244,salary,empname);
END;
/
```

It gives this error when executed:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
DECLARE 
  employee_name emp55.ename%TYPE;
  employee_salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
  emp_lookup (3244,salary,empname);

END;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 20:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SALARY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

It runs successfully but when I execute it

```
execute emp_lookup (3346, salary, empname);
```

shows this error:

```
Error starting at line : 16 in command -
BEGIN emp_lookup (3346, salary, empname); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 27:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SALARY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 54:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use bind variables  to pass as `OUT` parameters while calling.

```
VARIABLE sal NUMBER
VARIABLE name VARCHAR2(20)
execute emp_lookup (3346, :sal, :name)
```

If you are calling the procedure from within a PL/SQL block, you should have the `OUT` variables declared appropriately before calling.

```
DECLARE
salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
empname emp55.ename%TYPE;
BEGIN
   emp_lookup (3346, salary, empname);
END;
/
```

Comment: I did make a declaration
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
employee_name emp55.ename%TYPE;
employee_salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
emp_lookup (3244,salary,empname);

END;

Comment: @R.Al : edit the question add your complete code for procedure invocation.

Comment: it didn't work it shows this Error starting at line : 3 in command -
DECLARE 
employee_name emp55.ename%TYPE;
employee_salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
emp_lookup (3244,salary,empname);

END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 20:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SALARY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Error starting at line : 20 in command -
BEGIN emp_lookup (3346, :sal, :name); END;
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYS.EMP_LOOKUP", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: @R.Al `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at "SYS.EMP_LOOKUP` This error is nothing to do with the error you have in relation to the question. What Kaushik has provided with the answer will solve the issue you are having.

Comment: @R.Al : That error doesn't have anything to do with the way you are calling it. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779483/pl-sql-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-rows for how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

```
var salary number
var empname varchar2(10)
create or replace procedure emp_lookup
(no IN emp55.empno%TYPE,
salary OUT emp55.sal%TYPE,
empname OUT emp55.ename%TYPE)
IS
begin
select sal , ename INTO salary, empname
from emp55
where empno=no;

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN empname:='null';
salary:=-1;

execute emp_lookup (3346, :salary,:empname);
print salary
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** 
correct your procedure code (change the name of the input variable)

This correction is needed because your `where` clause (`where  empno=empno;`) is always `true`, so every row of the table will be returned  - which is clearly not your initial intention.

```
create or replace procedure emp_lookup
(in_empno IN emp55.empno%TYPE,
 salary OUT emp55.sal%TYPE,
 empname OUT emp55.ename%TYPE)
IS 
begin 
select sal , ename INTO salary, empname
from emp55 
where empno=in_empno;

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN empname:='null';
salary:=-1;

END;
```

**Secod** 
run as follows:

```
DECLARE 
  employee_name emp55.ename%TYPE;
  employee_salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
  emp_lookup (3244,employee_salary ,employee_name);
  dbms_output.put_line(employee_name   || ' ' || employee_salary);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare what 'salary' is: i.e.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
  empname emp55.ename%TYPE;
  salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
  emp_lookup (3244,salary,empname);
END;
/
```

else,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
  employee_name emp55.ename%TYPE;
  employee_salary emp55.sal%TYPE;
BEGIN
  emp_lookup (3244,employee_salary ,employee_name );
END;
/
```

I reckon, any of the above solutions would resolve your issue.