# Why do I have an error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, cursor, procedure

```
    1. create or replace procedure cities (
    2. vname in varchar2,
    3. vuni out varchar2
    4. ) as
    5. cursor c is
    6. select city_name, uni_name from uni ;
    7. cx c%rowtype;
    8. begin
    9. select uni_name into vuni from uni; 
    10. open c;
    11. loop
    12. fetch c into cx;
    13. exit when c%notfound;
    14. if (vname = 'Almaty') then
    15. select distinct cx.uni_name into vuni from uni where  cx.city_name = vname;
    16. elsif (vname = 'Nur-Sultan') then
    17. select distinct cx.uni_name into vuni from uni where cx.city_name = vname;
    18. elsif (vname = 'Aktau') then
    19. select distinct cx.uni_name into vuni from uni where cx.city_name = vname;
    20. else
    21. select distinct cx.uni_name into vuni from uni where cx.city_name = vname;
    22. end if;
    23. end loop;
    24. close c;
    25. end;
```

Comment: Why? Because some of SELECT DISTINCT statements returned more than a single value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779483/pl-sql-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-rows)

Comment: @OldProgrammer, no, when I change my code I have another error "No Data Found". Please, help :(

Comment: @Littlefoot, how can I fix yhis problem?

Comment: Scroll a little bit down, I posted some more info as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all `SELECT` statement outside of cursor.

The most suspicious looks the first one at line #9:

```
select uni_name into vuni from uni;
```

Unless `UNI` table contains only one row, this will return `too_many_rows`.

Other than that, there are several `SELECT DISTINCT` statements. If `DISTINCT` doesn't do its job, then either your data is wrong, or your code is wrong. Maybe you need to add yet another condition into the `WHERE` clause.

Whichever statement returns the error, the simplest option is to use one of aggregate functions, such as

```
select max(cx.uni_name) ...
```

as it'll return only one value, but - that's most probably the last option you should use.

---

**[EDIT]**

Wait a minute; yes, you got various errors, but - looking more closely to your code, it doesn't make much sense. First of all, it should have been a **function**, not a procedure:

```
create or replace function f_cities (par_vname in varchar2)
  return uni.uni_name%type
is
  retval uni.uni_name%type;
begin
  select u.uni_name
    into retval
    from u.uni
    where u.city_name = par_vname;

  return retval;
end;
```

If it has to be a procedure, then

```
create or replace procedure cities
  (par_vname in varchar2,
   par_vuni out varchar2
  )
is
begin
  select u.uni_name
    into par_vuni
    from u.uni
    where u.city_name = par_vname;
end;
```

As of your code:

- cursor you used is not necessary
- `select` statements are so strange; you're selecting a cursor variable value into the `OUT` parameter, from the same table cursor's `select` is based on
- `if`s are useless. It is the `in` parameter that says with city it is; you don't have to hardcode those values, as that procedure might become a real monster if there were many more cites in the table

Shortly, I suggest you use a function I posted above.

---

**[EDIT #2]**

Based on your comment: there can be several universities in a city. Therefore, you can't return a scalar value but *something else*, such as ref cursor or an array.

Suppose this is the table you have:

```
SQL> create table uni
  2    (city_name    varchar2(20),
  3     uni_name     varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into uni (city_name, uni_name)
  2    select 'Almaty', 'Uni 1'     from dual union all
  3    select 'Almaty', 'Uni2'      from dual union all
  4    select 'Nur-Sultan', 'Uni 4' from dual union all
  5    select 'Aktau', 'Uni 3'      from dual union all
  6    select 'Aktau', 'Uni 9'      from dual;

5 rows created.

SQL>
```

Now you could do the following:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_uni (par_city_name in varchar2)
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3  as
  4    rc sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    select uni_name
  7      bulk collect into rc
  8      from uni
  9      where city_name = par_city_name;
 10    return rc;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_uni('Almaty') from dual;

F_UNI('ALMATY')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('Uni 1', 'Uni2')
```

or

```
SQL> create or replace function f_uni (par_city_name in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  as
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select uni_name
  7          from uni
  8      where city_name = par_city_name;
  9    return rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_uni('Almaty') from dual;

F_UNI('ALMATY')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

UNI_NAME
--------------------
Uni 1
Uni2


SQL>
```

Comment: I have deleted line 9 and checked all select statements outside of cursor and they work outside of cursor. but i have an error "No Data Found" when i use my procedure

Comment: Have a look at EDIT I posted, please.

Comment: yeah, I have tried to use the function that u posted above, but again I have an error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". I really dont know what to do

Comment: It means that city name isn't unique in the table, so you might need to add another condition into the where clause (as I said previously). Maybe it is the province name, state name, ... I don't know what you have in that table.

Comment: I have a city and several universities in this city. and i should write procedure or function that will show me distinct names of universities in the city. I can enter, for example, Almaty and I want to see the list of all universities in Almaty. so in my db I can have for example 5 Almatys bc in almaty I have 5 universities. Do u understand?

Comment: Aha; got it now. OK, I edited my answer again, see edit #2, please.

Comment: oh, yeah, that is something like what i need, but i need this to use in php, so would it work if I will use this code(second one) in my php code? im asking this bc your code has SYS_recursor (it works with sql, will it work in php?)

Comment: (Sorry, went to sleep). I don't know, I don't speak php.