# Oracle: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables `COURSES` and `COURSE_PRICELIST` and I created this function in order to take a value and put this value to a variable:

```
create or replace function "GET_PUBLIC_COURSE_AMMOUNT" (course_id in number)
  return number
is
  TC_Ammount number;
begin
  select COURSE_PRICELIST.PRICE
    into TC_Ammount
    from COURSES
    join COURSE_PRICELIST 
      on COURSES.ID = COURSE_PRICELIST.COURSE_ID
   where COURSE_PRICELIST.ACTIVE = 1
     and COURSES.ID = course_id;
  return TC_Ammount;
end;
```

The problem is that when I run this `select` statement it returns only one row (this is exactly what i want), but when I am trying to use this statement as a function:

```
DECLARE
    TCPL NUMBER;
BEGIN
    TCPL := GET_PUBLIC_COURSE_AMMOUNT(90);  
END;
```

I have this error:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
>
> ORA-06512: at "PAADB.GET_PUBLIC_COURSE_AMMOUNT", line 8
>
> ORA-06512: at line 4
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

I am sure that the result of this function is just one row and I don't want to use `cursor`.

Comment: Well, obviously your `SELECT` does return more than one row. You need to check your parameter and execute the function with exactly the same `course_id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779483/pl-sql-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-rows)

Comment: Thanks for your response! With the restriction (COURSE_PRICELIST.ACTIVE =1) for every course_id i have only one active price, i triple checked it. Maybe the problem is because the course_id is fk to my second table (COURSE_PRICELIST) and allows to add more than once the same course_id in this table....For example i have the course_id =90 three times in this table but only one is active.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is function parameter `course_id` that has the same name as column in table `COURSE_PRICELIST`. Therefore in `select` it behaves like `1 = 1` and returns all rows.

It is good practice to prefix variables and parameters in PL/SQL so such mistakes don't happen, some examples:

- Variables: v_
- Constants: c_
- Cursors: cur_
- Parameters: p_
- Types: t_ (or append _tabt/_rect)
- and many others..

Try:

```
create or replace function GET_PUBLIC_COURSE_AMMOUNT (p_course_id in number)
  return number
is
  v_TC_Ammount number;
begin
  select COURSE_PRICELIST.PRICE
    into v_TC_Ammount
    from COURSES
    join COURSE_PRICELIST 
      on COURSES.ID = COURSE_PRICELIST.COURSE_ID
   where COURSE_PRICELIST.ACTIVE = 1
     and COURSES.ID = p_course_id;
  return v_TC_Ammount;
end;
```

Comment: With pleasure, please don't forget to mark your question as answered. Have a nice day.