# For loop in Oracle sql for calculating transaction balance. ORA_01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of row

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, ora-01422

I am trying to write a For loop program which will calculate total balance for each account.  But I am getting this error

> ORA_01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of row

Below is my script

```
DECLARE
v_area          VARCHAR2(3);
v_account_no   VARCHAR2(20);
v_cur        VARCHAR2(3);
v_local_bal    NUMBER;
v_fo_bal    NUMBER;

BEGIN
  FOR y IN (SELECT area,cur,account_no FROM accounts 
    WHERE account_no IN ('1123456879','2222222222','3333333333','4444444444','5555555555','6666666666','7777777777'))
    LOOP
      SELECT area,accno,cur,SUM(DECODE(drcr, 'C', local_amt, -local_amt)) local_bal,NVL(SUM(DECODE(drcr, 'C', fo_amt, -fo_amt)), 0) fo_bal
      INTO v_area, v_account_no, v_cur, v_local_bal, v_fo_bal
      FROM transactions
      WHERE acc_number = y.account_no
      AND transdate <= '29Dec2023'
      AND area = '234'
      GROUP BY area, acc_number, cur;

    -- Display individual account balances
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Account: ' || y.account_no|| ', Area: ' || v_area || ', Curr: ' || v_cur);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Local Balance: ' || v_local_bal);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FO Balance: ' || v_fo_bal);

   
END LOOP;

END;/
```

Here is the output I am expecting

```
Account: 1123456879, Area: 234 , Curr: XYX, Local Balance: 2000 FO Balance: 500
Account: 2222222222, Area: 234 , Curr: XXX, Local Balance: 1000 FO Balance: 0
Account: 3333333333, Area: 234 , Curr: XXX, Local Balance: 1000 FO Balance: 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779483/pl-sql-ora-01422-exact-fetch-returns-more-than-requested-number-of-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Query is invalid and doesn't even have a chance of returning that error because you're

- selecting `area, accno, cur`
- and grouping by `area, acc_number, cur`

Once that's fixed, **then** it might return too many rows.

---

Let's presume that you actually wanted to select `acc_number`. Then

This:

```
SELECT area,acc_number,cur,SUM(DECODE(drcr, 'C', local_amt, -local_amt)) local_bal,
       NVL(SUM(DECODE(drcr, 'C', fo_amt, -fo_amt)), 0) fo_bal
  INTO v_area, v_account_no, v_cur, v_local_bal, v_fo_bal
  FROM transactions
  WHERE acc_number = y.account_no
  AND transdate <= '29Dec2023'
  AND area = '234'
  GROUP BY area, acc_number, cur;
```

doesn't return a single row for each `y.account_no`.

- `area` should be OK, it is a *constant* (`234`)
- therefore, `acc_number` and `cur` remain suspicious

What to do? Depends on what you want; you can aggregate them as well, for example

```
  SELECT area,
         LISTAGG (acc_number, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY acc_number) AS accno,
         LISTAGG (cur, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cur) AS cur,
         SUM (DECODE (drcr, 'C', local_amt, -local_amt)) local_bal,
         NVL (SUM (DECODE (drcr, 'C', fo_amt, -fo_amt)), 0) fo_bal
    INTO v_area,
         v_account_no,
         v_cur,
         v_local_bal,
         v_fo_bal
    FROM transactions
   WHERE     acc_number = y.account_no
         AND transdate <= '29Dec2023'
         AND area = '234'
GROUP BY area;
```

Or, you can use loop within a loop and display several rows for each `y.account_no` (but that's not what your expected output suggests).

---

Besides, what is `transactions.transdate` column's datatype? Query you posted suggests it is a string (`varchar2`). Should be `date`, which is what value (`23Dec2023`) suggests. If you're relying on implicit datatype conversion and NLS settings, don't. A better option would be e.g.

```
and transdate <= date '2023-12-29'
```